# jquery ajax working fine but angular ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, rest

I am making an AJAX call using jQuery and it works fine. However, when I use AngularJS to carry out the same AJAX request, I am fine as long as a success is returned. But, if an error occurs, no response is returned and the error is displayed in my browser console.

**jQuery call:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myUrl,
    data: a javascript object,
    dataType: "json",               
    //if received a response from the server
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response,'in success');
        callback(response)
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response.status,'in error');
        callback(response)
    }
})
```

**AngularJS Call:**

```
$http({
    url: myUrl,
    method: "POST",
    data: $.param(javascriptObject),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
}).success(//reached Here in case of Success
    function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(response,'in     success');
        callback(response)
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //Never Reached Here
    console.log(response.status,'in error');
    callback(response)
});
```

**MyController:**

```
//some logic
if(flag==false) {
    return Response.status(403).entity(msg).build();    
} else {
    return Response.status(200).entity(msg).build();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$http({
    url: myUrl,
    method: "POST",
    data: $.param(javascriptObject),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
}).then(function(response) {
    // your success logic here   
}).catch(function(reason){
    // your error reason here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the header for the ajax request.
Unless I am mistaken, angular does not set the headers for XMLHttpRequest, but JQuery does.